# Dual booting W7 and Ubuntu on separate hard drives.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I already have W7 on a WD hard drive, I got a Seagate hard drive I want to dedicate to Ubuntu. I popped in the disk and went to install, but a notification popped up asking me if I wanted to force UEFI (or go back), and something about only running one OS with this. I clicked go back and quit install. How would I properly dual boot these two on separate hard drives?

Comment: Is hardware UEFI or BIOS? And then is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. Better to have Ubuntu installed in same boot mode. How you boot install media from flash drive is how it installs. But with Ubuntu you can still use gpt partitioning and boot in BIOS mode. With Something Else install option be sure to install grub2's boot loader into MBR of sdb or Ubuntu drive. You want to keep Windows boot loader on Windows drive. Or disconnect Windows drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go about this.

The legacy method will have you boot from one drive and choose which OS you want to boot. Boot control then transfers to the appropriate HDD. In this scenario GRUB is installed to the MBR of the boot drive. This could be your Windows or Linux drive. You could also install GRUB to both drives just in case the first drive suffers a failure.

But in your case, UEFI is enabled.

The UEFI method generally sees boot entries written to the BIOS so that the Windows and Linux installations are effectively isolated from one another. You would boot either OS by hitting your Boot Menu key (usually F12) and choose which one you want to boot, or it will boot the "default" OS that is first in the boot order of your BIOS setup.